# Camel use old header after use pollEnrich

Tags: apache-camel

my goal is to read 2 files.
My logic is as follows:
I read the first file if it is txt imposed by the various headers, after which I read the second file through pollEnrich but the headers I previously set no longer exist.
Below is my code:

```
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route id="StartProcessCamunda">
    <!--Questa linea di codice guarda la cartella input e quando viene inserito un file lo muove dentro la cartella processed/data di oggi/ se non esiste la data di oggi la crea  -->
    <from uri="file:/input?move=processed/${date:now:dd-MM-yyyy}/${file:name}"/>  
    

    <setHeader name="OnlyFileNamePDF"> 
        <simple>
            ${file:onlyname.noext}
        </simple>
    </setHeader>
    <choice>
        <when>
            <simple>${file:ext} == "pdf"</simple>
            
           
            
            <log message="Prima poll = ${header.FileNamePDF}"/>

            <pollEnrich>
                <simple>file:/input?fileName=${header.OnlyFileNamePDF}.xml&amp;noop=true</simple> 
            </pollEnrich>

            <log message="Dopo poll = ${header.FileNamePDF}"/>

            <marshal>
                <base64 lineLength="100000000000" />
            </marshal>

            <setHeader name="FileXML">
                <simple>${bodyAs(String).lines[0]}</simple>
            </setHeader>

            
            <setHeader name="FileNameXML"> 
                <simple>
                    ${file:name}
                </simple>
            </setHeader>
            

        </when>
    </choice>
</route>
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested this out with Java-DSL and it looks like calling pollEnrich either clears the headers or replaces the message with new one. Use exchange properties instead with [setProperty](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/setProperty-eip.html) and refer to it with `${exchangeProperty.FileNamePDF}` instead.

Comment: No problem. You can mark my [answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @PasiÖsterman hey pal. Could you please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73744474/fixed-name-in-apache-camel-looking-for-specific-file It drives me crazy :/