# fixed name in apache-camel, looking for specific file

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, esb

I built a API-REST service to obtain specific PDF documents stored in a FTP directory by passing different arguments to the URL.

I'm using APACHE-CAMEL and JAVA

Example:

My URL looks like this:

> http://server3343.erp.local:5464/api/rest/invoices/receipts/pdf?companyNumber=45&accountNumber=000333&documentType=FC&transactionNumber=BG534530SF

These parameters are completed to look for a file, in the given example i set:

```
companyNumber: 45
accountNumber: 000333
documentType: FC
transactionNumber: BG534530SF
```

The PDF file has this name:

```
45000333FCBG534530SF
```

---

**The problem is that it takes 20 or 25 seconds or even higher to get a document and i wonder how can i improve search time while searching for a file**

**This is my code:**

```
package ar.com.project.esb.route;

import ar.com.project.camel.common.route.RestRouteBuilder;
import ar.com.project.esb.Constants;
import org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel;
import org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestParamType;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Component
public class GetReceiptsPDFRoute extends RestRouteBuilder {

    @Value("${timeout.FTP}")
    private Long timeoutFTP;

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        super.configure();
        rest(restApiPath)
            .get("/receipts/pdf?companyNumber={companyNumber}&accountNumber={accountNumber}&documentType={documentType}&transactionNumber={transactionNumber}").id("receipts PDF")
            .param().name("companyNumber").type(RestParamType.query).dataType("String").required(true).endParam()
            .param().name("accountNumber").type(RestParamType.query).dataType("String").required(true).endParam()
            .param().name("documentType").type(RestParamType.query).dataType("String").required(true).endParam()
            .param().name("transactionNumber").type(RestParamType.query).dataType("String").required(true).endParam()
            .consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .produces("application/pdf")
            .to("direct:receiptsPDF");

        /**
         *  set name and location to find PDF documents in FTP directory
         */
        from("direct:receiptsPDF").routeId("ReceiptsPDF")
            .setProperty("currentOperation", constant("ReceiptsPDF"))
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"getClaimStatus", "[Inicia ${property.currentOperation}]")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "company Number: ${header.companyNumber}")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "account Number: ${header.accountNumber}")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "document Type: ${header.documentType}")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "transaction Type: ${header.transactionNumber}")
            .doTry()
                .choice()
                    .when(header("documentType").isEqualTo(Constants.RECEIPT))
                        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "[${property.currentOperation}] Find RECEIPT")
                        .setHeader("TARGET_DIR", constant("{{source.erp.RECEIPTs}}"))
                .endChoice()
                .otherwise()
                    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "[${property.currentOperation}] Find DOCUMENTS")
                    .setHeader("TARGET_DIR", constant("{{source.erp.DOCUMENTS}}"))
                .end()
                .setProperty("fileName", simple("${header.companyNumber}${header.accountNumber}${header.documentType}${header.transactionNumber}.pdf"))
                .to("direct:findPdfInFTP")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"getClaimStatus", "[Ending ${property.currentOperation}]")
            .endDoTry()
            .doCatch(Exception.class)
                .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "getReceipts", "[ERROR: ${exception.message}")
        .end();

        /**
         *  Search in FTP directory
         */
        from("direct:findPdfInFTP").routeId("find file in ftp")
            .doTry()
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Search: ${header.TARGET_DIR}/${property.fileName}")
                .pollEnrich().simple("{{erp.sftp}}/${header.TARGET_DIR}?password={{erp.sftp.password}}&fileName=${property.fileName}&disconnect=true&noop=true&recursive=true&useUserKnownHostsFile=false&idempotent=false&include=.*.pdf").timeout(timeoutFTP)
                .choice()
                    .when(simple("${body} == null"))
                        .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "getClaimStatus", "[ERROR: file does not exist...]")
                .otherwise()
                    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"FILE OBTAINED: ${headers.CamelFileName}")
            .endDoTry()
            .doCatch(Exception.class)
                .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "getReceipts", "[ERROR: ${exception.message}")
        .end();
    }
}
```

---

A guy told me about making an attempt to download it instead of searching, using a fixed name and gave me this link:  https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/ftp-component.html#_consuming_a_single_file_using_a_fixed_name

Don't know how to make it work on my code, could you please help me?

Comment: Not sure about this one, but last time I checked ( albeit with older Camel version) `noop=true` and `idempotent=false` options don't work together.  Had to set the file-consumer endpoint to use [DummIdempotentRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30353440/16480631) for it to read the same file more than once.  It's also weird that you're using both `fileName` option and `include` option as file extension needs to be specified with the fileName option for it to work.

Comment: Hey @PasiÖsterman pal, thank you very much for replying, you're amazing!.
I do not fully understand how should i modify my code in order to make it work. I'm a little confused right now

Comment: Like I said I am not sure whats causing your problem. But if you look at the documentation `noop=true` and `idempotent=false` are **conflicting** settings.  Instead you'll need to add **custom** [Dummy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352792/poll-files-from-read-only-filesystem-repeatedly-idempotent-false-with-apache-c/30353440#30353440) IdempotentRepository to camel registry and refer to it from your URI `ftp:host:port/directoryName?noop=true&idempotentRepository=#bean:DummyIdempotentRepository` .  This will allow you to read same file multiple times with file and ftp componetns.

Comment: @PasiÖsterman My code does work but i do not understand how to implement the "fixed name" solution provided https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/ftp-component.html#_consuming_a_single_file_using_a_fixed_name . My code works but it takes 20 or 30 seconds to download a PDF

Comment: @PasiÖsterman somebody told me to make my code more efficient and he said "use the fixed name" approach but that's where i don't know what to do

Comment: Well according to the documentation having `&useList=false&ignoreFileNotFoundOrPermissionError=true&fileName=${property.fileName}` should be enough. However with `useList=false` the `recursive=true` and `include=.*.pdf` options will probably not work.

Comment: @PasiÖsterman yeah, totally. But i don't want to lose that. Do you get me? I just want to make my code more fast. It takes 20 or 30 seconds to download a PDF and that's why i'm looking for something else

Comment: @PasiÖsterman i'm having trouble while adding the custom Dummy IdempotentRepository to camel registry in order t o use Idempotent

Comment: You need to add Dummy IdempotentRepository as a bean to camels registery.  Haven't used SpringBoot much so don't know what is the best way to do this. Maybe using `org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelContextConfiguration` bean with `beforeApplicationStart` method to add  it to the registry `context.getRegistry().bind("DummyIdempotentRepository", DummyIdempotentRepository.class, new DummyIdempotentRepository());`

Comment: Gonna check that out, @PasiÖsterman thank you :)

Comment: @PasiÖsterman Pal, take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73796081/pollenrich-apache-camel-trying-to-improve-search-download-performance-time  How would you improve it?